# Strange message (_Base_bitset::_M_do_to_ulong) getting printed out of overflow exception handler

Tags: c++, exception

I was trying my hands on exception handling & this code is not throwing the string it is intended to:

```
           bitset<134> b;
           b.set();
           try{
                    if(!b.to_ulong())
                    throw std::overflow_error("Overflow occured\n");
           }
           catch(std::overflow_error& e)
           {
                    cout<<e.what();
           }
```

The output is:

> _Base_bitset::_M_do_to_ulong

Whereas when I replace the **if** condition with this

```
        if(3>2)
```

The expected string is printed. Whats going on in this?

Comment: @user4581301 So how can one print the error message one wants to print in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on: `b.to_ulong();` throws `std::overflow_error` with its own message if the bitfield won't fit into a `unsigned long` before you get the chance to. The `if` never gets tested.

The `if` test is doomed anyway. It will throw the exception on any non-zero value returned by `b.to_ulong()`. Not what you want.

Easiest way I can think of to get your message is to catch the exception thrown by `to_ulong` and throwing your own.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bitset < 134 > b;
    b.set();
    try
    {
        b.to_ulong();
    }
    catch (std::overflow_error& e)
    {
        throw std::overflow_error("Overflow occured\n");
    }
}
```

It might be faster to perform the testing yourself rather than calling `to_ulong` and dealing with two exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
bitset<134> b;
b.set();                            // all bits in the set are 1's
try
{
    if (!b.to_ulong())              // throws its own std::overflow_error()!
        throw std::overflow_error("Overflow occured\n");  // doesn't reach.
}
catch(std::overflow_error& e)
{
    cout << e.what();               // catches the exception thrown by b.to_ulong()
}
```